# Child with position absolute has full parent height

Tags: css, flexbox

Trying to recreate this layout:

[image]

The problem is the white box on top of the black. I don't know the height of the black box. How can I create the white box on top of the others?

This is my code:

https://codepen.io/olefrankjensen/pen/oQyZpX?editors=1100

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="formbox">[login form markup here...]</div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Don't have an account</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dicta cumque harum.</p>
    <button>SIGN UP</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Have an account</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus dicta cumque harum.</p>
    <button>LOGIN</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
// reset
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, button, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

// font
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

// colors
$white: rgba(255,255,255,.8);

:root {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(
https://picsum.photos/1200/800?);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: $white;
}

.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  padding: 5rem 3rem;
  float: left;

  h1, p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  button {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid $white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: $white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;   
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

.formbox {
  width: 500px;
  background: white;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I have to absolute position the `.formbox` to not make it "interfere" with the other flex items in the flex container `.container`. But as a consequence it has no height.

How can I give the Login overlay full height of it's parent?

Comment: `top:0;bottom:0;`

Answer (score 1):

When position is absolute, `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` properties work relative to the first parent with `position: relative`.

So, you don't really need the `margin-top: -25px` or `margin-left: -50px`, you can just add `top: -25px; bottom: -25px; left: -25px` to `.formbox` and you are done. If you need to move it to the right, just add `right: XXpx` and remove `left` (or set a positive value like `left: 50%`).

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQKWNq?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

I could go with adding to formbox class a height of 100% + 50px (margin -25px what you have took x 2). You can do this with calc function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

```
.formbox {
    width: 500px;
    background: white;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px black;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: calc(100% + 50px);
}
```